# How to visualize similarity metrics as a table with color map?

Tags: python, visualization

I would like to visualize results of euclidean, mape, and correlation metric values in a table with color coding and color map that shows level of similarity of prediction and ground truth data. Estimated data has 2 different Inspections. I would like to see similarity of prediction and ground truth data for each inspection. In each inspection, I calculate similarity metric for Day and Night time separately.. Using the script below, I can print out metric value calculations, and similarity level which I adjusted according to my needs.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def calc_euclidean(actual, predic):
    return np.sqrt(np.sum((actual - predic) ** 2))

def calc_mape(actual, predic):
    return np.mean(np.abs((actual - predic) / actual))

def calc_correlation(actual, predic):
    a_diff = actual - np.mean(actual)
    p_diff = predic - np.mean(predic)
    numerator = np.sum(a_diff * p_diff)
    denominator = np.sqrt(np.sum(a_diff ** 2)) * np.sqrt(np.sum(p_diff ** 2))
    return numerator / denominator

def analyze_similarity(a, b):
    if calc_euclidean(a, b) < 100 and calc_mape(a, b) < 0.1 and calc_correlation(a, b) > 0.8:
        return "Highly similar"
    elif calc_mape(a, b) < 500 and calc_correlation(a, b) > 0.5:
        return "Moderately Similar"
    elif calc_correlation(a, b) < -0.5:
        return "Highly Dissimilar"
    elif calc_correlation(a, b) < 0.1:
        return "Low Dissimilarity"
    else:
        return "Moderate Dissimilarity"

def categorize_similarity(correlation_value):
    if correlation_value >= 0.9:
        return "Highly Similar"
    elif correlation_value >= 0.7:
        return "Moderately Similar"
    elif correlation_value >= 0.5:
        return "Low Dissimilar"
    elif correlation_value >= 0.3:
        return "Moderate Dissimilarity"
    else:
        return "Highly Dissimilar"

estimated_x_1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [12, 22, 32, 42, 52, 62, 21, 41, 22, 23, 41, 12],
                              'TIMEDAY': ['Day', 'Day', 'Day', 'Night', 'Night', 'Night', 'Night', 'Night', 'Night', 'Day', 'Day', 'Day'],
                              'INSPECTION': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]})

ground_truth_x = pd.DataFrame({'a': [6, 44, 12, 84, 26, 31],
                                'TIMEDAY': ['Day', 'Day', 'Day', 'Night', 'Night', 'Night']})


for inspection in estimated_x_1['INSPECTION'].unique():
    for timeday in estimated_x_1['TIMEDAY'].unique():
        
        current_estimated = estimated_x_1[(estimated_x_1['INSPECTION'] == inspection) & (estimated_x_1['TIMEDAY'] == timeday)]['a'].values
        current_ground_truth = ground_truth_x[ground_truth_x['TIMEDAY'] == timeday]['a'].values

        similarity_result = analyze_similarity(current_estimated, current_ground_truth)
        correlation_value = calc_correlation(current_estimated, current_ground_truth)
        categorized_similarity = categorize_similarity(correlation_value)

        print(f"Inspection {inspection} {timeday} Time:")
        print(f"Estimated Values: {current_estimated}")
        print(f"Ground Truth Values: {current_ground_truth}")
        print(f"Euclidean Distance: {calc_euclidean(current_estimated, current_ground_truth)}")
        print(f"MAPE: {calc_mape(current_estimated, current_ground_truth)}")
        print(f"Correlation: {correlation_value}")
        print(f"Similarity Analysis: {similarity_result}")
        print(f"Categorized Similarity: {categorized_similarity}")
        print("\n")
```

I attempted to solve the problem with

```py
pivot_df = results_df.pivot(index='Inspection', columns='Time', values='Similarity')
cmap = sns.light_palette("seagreen", as_cmap=True)
sns.heatmap(pivot_df, annot=True, cmap=cmap, cbar_kws={'label': 'Similarity'})
```

However, there were many errors. Hence, I do not know how to precced from this point.
**Expectation:**

Using the script above, how can I create a data table with color map to make a plot of similrity metric? On the table, I would like to see only result of Similarity along with color map that show analyze_similarity condition. The color map should have low and high, if deviation from ground truth high, then indicates on the table with dark color. Here is what I expect: